# Nginx is showing 400 Bad Request No required SSL certificate was sent

Tags: nginx, ssl

I'm trying to establish SSL connection, and I'm getting 400 No required SSL certificate was sent response from the server.

I used [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-a-website-using-cloudflare-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04) for it
I tried everything to solve this issue, but it seems that there is something wrong with the Cloudflare certificate because when I disable ssl_verify_client it is working (with security alert).
Here is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/key.pem;

    ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/cloudflare.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/username/www/exampleproject;
    }
    location /media/ {
        root /home/username/www/exampleproject;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/username/www/exampleproject/exampleproject.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is off-topic in StackOverflow. You have a better chance to get it answered if you move it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: *"I tried everything to solve this issue"* - which says exactly nothing about what you actually did. Based on the error *"No required SSL certificate was sent"* you likely haven't *Authenticated Origin Pulls* enabled, so Cloudflare does not send the client certificate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I've enabled "Authenticated Origin Pulls".